# MouseButtons::Left in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to check the left button is the pressed one.

I red on Msdna:

```
if(e->Button == MouseButtons.Left) {...}
//or
if(e->Button == ::MouseButtons.Left) {...}
```

But no one of them compiles.

Comment: Where did you see `e->Button == MouseButtons.Left` on MSDN?  That's wrong and I'll file a bug report if there's any page that actually says that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an annoyance of the C++ language, inherited by C++/CLI.  It puts the names of types and the names of class members in the same symbol table.  This is something you'll battle often when you write Winforms code in C++/CLI instead of C# or VB.NET, languages that keep type identifiers separate.

There's an ambiguity between the MouseButtons enum type and the Form class' MouseButtons property, they are both in scope here.  IntelliSense stops helping you to get the syntax right which is probably how you ended up with . instead of :: Leaving no odds anymore to get a decent compiler error message.  You resolve the ambiguity by writing the enum type name in full:

```
     if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left) {
         // etc...
     }
```

Problems like these are probably one reason that C++/CLI never got very popular.  Then again, C# is rather a class act.  Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the event on control you want:

```
this->control->MouseDown += new System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &Form1::control_MouseDown);
```

and handle it like this:

```
void control_MouseDown(Object* sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs* e) {    
    if(e->Button == MouseButtons::Left) {
       //code here
    }
}
```